# What is the best way to convert a block number to a file name in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

Today I found the following message in the daily log mail I get from a FreeBSD server:

```
ad2c: hard error reading fsbn 1081249272 of 540624636-540624639 (ad2 bn 1081249272; cn 1072667 tn 14 sn 54) status=59 error=40
```

What is the best way to find the file corresponding to above block number?

Comment: Side note: Hard errors on modern HDs *usually* mean imminent death. Got backups?

Comment: Might be a bit late to save this disk considering the age of the question, but @ChrisS definitely has a good point.  You don't see Hard Errors often these days with SMART drives, but when you do it's generally time to plan a viking funeral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and probably have to) resort to `fsdb`(8) for this -- the `findblk` command should be able to track down the inode, from which you can get the file name.

```
OBLIGATORY WARNING
fsdb is a pretty dangerous tool. You can do a lot of damage in a very short amount of time.
It is a good idea to read the man page thoroughly, and perhaps peruse a few other sources
of information before poking around in the dark sticky guts of your filesystem.
```

More details can be found in [this mailing list post to freebsd-questions](http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-questions@freebsd.org/msg172755.html)